# How to get parameter value from "parameter = 'value' using Regular Expressions in LibreOffice Writter?

Tags: regex, libreoffice

I really need help in this problem I just cant figure it out. We are using LibreOffice Writters regular expression.

Example:
name = "James" 
job = "teacher"

Result:
name James 
job Teacher

This is the result I am looking for, thank you for all the answers and I apologize for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: I don't even know how to start, example "name = 'jon' " I can get, jon or name, but how do I get both together? We are using the control + h function, Find and Replace in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Hi RandomPerson Welcome to Stackoverflow. How can we help? Do you mean writer or BASE ? is this a databse form in writer ?